# How does Codable validate the type it extends?

Tags: swift, codable

I came across this brilliant compile-time error and I'm trying to figure out how it works.

Here it is, boiled down to its most basic form.

```
struct Object: Codable {
    let a: Int
    let b: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a
        case b
    }
}
```

The above snippet compiles just fine, as expected.  However, the following snippet fails because it does not conform to the type `Decodable`:

```
struct Object: Codable {
    let a: Int
    let b: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a
    }
}
```

My assumption is that Swift somehow expects the enum `CodingKeys` to contain a case for each property defined on `Object`.

Is this assumption correct, and if so, how does Swift know that?

Comment: It is special cased compiler magic. Not something we can do on our own :/

Comment: Swift somehow expects the `enum CodingKeys` to contain a case for each property defined on `Object`. Yep. What's mysterious about that? It's a pretty trivial thing for the compiler to check

Comment: @Alexander what's mysterious to me is that it's not obvious how this works by looking at the declaration for `Decodable`.  If @OscarApeland is correct, that answers my question but also leaves a void in my soul.

Comment: @jperl Ah, I see what you mean now. Yes, `Decodable` is a "magic" protocol. It's a protocol in Swift land, but its implementation is provided by the compiler, and not expressible in Swift. The same goes for `ExpressibleForIntegerLiteral`, `Hashable` (with regards to its compiler-synthesized implementations), etc.

Comment: If Swift had meta-programming capabilities like D, Rust, or C++'s template (*shudders*), then the implementation of Codable might actually be expressed in Swift, but alas, there is no such meta programming scheme.

Comment: Note that the compiler only performs this check because it's trying to synthesise an implementation of `init(from:)` for you, and that implementation requires a coding key for each stored property. If you provide your own implementation of `init(from:)`, it won't do this check.